# Enabling events C# VSTO Workbook

Tags: c#, vba, events, vsto

I have a VSTO workbook. I have a set of security measures that check the users credentials when opening the file (checks e-mail account exchange and other company security policies) which ensures that only someone within the company can open the file.

I do this in the startup property; however, I know a simple way to get round this is to simply have another workbook open and set `enableevents` to `false` in VBA. This will stop the security check from firing.

Is there a way to always ensure that events are active?

I have tried checking if the events are turned on but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Isn't this what active directory and file system security are meant to do? Why are you reinventing the wheel with your own (not overly secure) methods?

Comment: Because the file has to be distributed to users that are not always connected to a network, therefore they could potentially save a copy onto a USB stick and give it to a competitor so I am simply trying to ensure that it will only run on a company computer.

Comment: If the security check hasn't run then why not just have the add-in disable itself?

Comment: So if they are not connected to a network, how pretel do you expect to perform a security check?

Comment: Hi Tim, it's a workbook not an add in so cannot just disable it unfortunately.

Comment: Hi Micky, because all of the company laptops have set policies on their computer which are company specific. So checking a couple of policies ensures it's a company laptop.

Comment: @JosephSargeant - Use the `@` notation when responding to someone then they get a notification and it makes the comments easier to follow.

Comment: @JosephSargeant - Does this help? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Information-Rights-Management-in-Office-2010-c7a70797-6b1e-493f-acf7-92a39b85e30c

Comment: @JosephSargeant - Or this? https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Activate-Rights-Management-RMS-in-the-Office-365-admin-center-5b6d3ac7-b1ac-428e-b03e-50e882f85a6e

Comment: *So checking a couple of policies ensures it's a company laptop* - nope.

Comment: @enigmativity thank you for the suggestions I will have a look into them. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Excel workbooks are not secure. Period.

Embedded code can always be viewed, changed, removed and/or disabled.

The data can be typically be accessed without even opening Excel.

Comment: Hi Thunder, yes I know that and I know it will never be 100% secure but just wanted to make it as secure as I could. If my original question isn't possible then that's ok.

Comment: @JosephSargeant Someone that's not supposed to have the file, that has the file, **will** be able to read its contents, regardless of what pseudo-security annoyances you put in... especially if that "security" is implemented with VBA code, which doesn't even run if macros are disabled... and Excel disables macros by default on any workbook that came from an email, thwarting anything you might have done in VBA to "secure" your workbook. Delete that code, it's useless.